# List with elements that attaches the top magically when scrolling

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

## Context

I have a `div` with `overflow: auto` property.

In this `div`, I have this:

```
<h3>Category 1</h3>
<ul>
    <li>blabla</li>
    <li>blabla</li>
    etc...
</ul>
<h3>Category 2</h3>
<ul>
    <li>blabla</li>
    <li>blabla</li>
    etc...
</ul>
<h3>Category 3</h3>
    etc...
```

I would like when I scroll, the current category attaches the top of the div, until the next category. When I arrive at an other category, it attaches the top in place of the previous.

Difficult to explain, so I made an image:

[image]

I'm sure I saw this in a website, but I don't remember.

## Questions

- Do you know a plugin for this or a site with this?
- Can you give me some tracks to develop it?

Comment: Good software can seem like magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSFiddle Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/h2p6W/3/

Attach an event listener to your scrollable div and measure the headers' positions in the div.  Then pick the one that is the small negative value and display it's text to your header.

```
$('#scroller').scroll(function () {
    var positions = $('h3', this).map(function() {
            return {
                top: $(this).position().top,
                el: this
            };
        }).get();

    //Go backwards through the array and pick the first negative (smallest) value
    for(var i = positions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(positions[i].top < 0) {
           $('#header').text($(positions[i].el).text());
           return;
        }
    }
});
```

For instance, if you have 5 headers in your scrollable div, and the positions are:

`[-100, -50, -20, 30, 120]` -  Then the `-20` is the header you want to display.

**EDIT - refactored code**

JSFiddle Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/h2p6W/4/

```
$('#scroller').scroll(function () {
    var category = '';

    $($('h3', this).get().reverse()).each(function () {
        if($(this).position().top < 0) {
            category = $(this).text();
            return false;
        }
    });

   $('#header').text(category);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add an `eventListener` to the window that updates every time the user scrolls the window. Then, compare the top position of the headers with the current scroll position. If the scroll position is greater than the header's position, change the header. Otherwise, or if a header has already been resized, don't do anything.

Here's some sample code. Feel free to tailor it to your liking.

```
<div style="position:fixed;right:0px;" id="place">Category 1</div>

<h3>Category 1</h3>
<ul>
    <li>blabla</li>
    <li>blabla</li>
    etc...
</ul>
<h3>Category 2</h3>
<ul>
    <li>blabla</li>
    <li>blabla</li>
    etc...
</ul>
<h3>Category 3</h3>
<ul>
    <li>blabla</li>
    <li>blabla</li>
    etc...
</ul>


<script>

var headers = document.getElementsByTagName("h3");

var place = document.getElementById("place");

addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {

    var scroll = document.body.scrollTop;
    var foundHeader = false;

    for(var i = headers.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {

        var h = headers[i];
        var top = h.offsetTop;


        if(!foundHeader && scroll+50 > top) {
            place.innerHTML = h.innerHTML;
            foundHeader = true;
        }




    }

}, true);

</script>
```

Edit: Changed the code to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: In case you want to do something to non-headers, you may want to replace the `foundHeader=true` with a `break`, since there isn't any reason to continue through the loop after that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some examples and how to: http://www.mustafaozcan.net/en/page/jQuery-Fixed-Table-Header-Plugin.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Twitter bootstrap have some similar feature: [fixed navbar](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar) with [scrollspy](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy).